# \Auth::user() is null in 5.3.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

## This is about Laravel 5.3.6

I am able to login successfully and I can check Auth User after login. I can show the exact location where `Auth::guard()` has current user object. Below are the details.

> 1. Go to Login Controller
> 2. Go to AuthenticatesUsers Trait
> 3. Go to sendLoginResponse method. User reaches here successfully because user is authenticated successfully.

here I can check `$this->guard()->user()` has current user value. But when control reaches to Role controller....I tried to access it like this `dd(Auth::guard());` and value was null. I also added reference below in Role Controller.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Below is my route for Role Controller.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/Roles',              
        array (
            'uses'  => 'Website\Role\RoleController@index',      
            'as'    => 'Roles'
        )
    );
});
```

Did you face this kind of issue in Laravel 5.3.6?

Output of `\Auth::guard()` is below.

```
SessionGuard {#162 ▼
  #name: "web"
  #lastAttempted: null
  #viaRemember: false
  #session: Store {#165 ▶}
  #cookie: CookieJar {#167 ▶}
  #request: Request {#40 ▶}
  #events: Dispatcher {#5 ▶}
  #loggedOut: false
  #tokenRetrievalAttempted: false
  #user: null
  #provider: EloquentUserProvider {#158 ▶}
}
```

Comment: did you override any methods in the Login controller if so then please post it

Comment: No, I did not override any method.

Comment: Did entire dd(Auth::guard()); was null or only "user" part, can you please post the controller? Before you reach controller route the dd(Auth::guard()); geves you the collection?

Comment: @RoccoMilluzzo : Thanks for the response. I have updated the question with details. Please let me know if there is anything still need for clarification.

Comment: Honestly I'ts very strange, looks like it doesn't keep the user logged in, doe it happens only on roles or in every other page? I've tried in 2 projects one 5.2 and one 5.3 but I'm not able to recreate the issue.

Comment: It happens on every page. But why it shoes current user session in login controller after authentication and does not show when it is redirected to role controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kernel.php file was like below**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

**I changed it to like below.**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```